# update student ordered by Batch.dateCreated asc where Batch.PK and Student.BatchFK matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in sql server - Student and Batch.

The student table is of this nature -

```
ID | studentname | batchTypeFfk | batchName
1  | Rob         | 1            |  Eng
```

The batch table is of this nature -

```
ID | name | batchTypeFk | date
1  | Eng  | 1           | 05/18/2019
2  | Mtt  | 1           | 05/20/2019
```

The batch type is of this nature -

```
ID | name  |
1  | Summer
```

My challenge is to sort batch table by date ascending and update the Student.batchName table with the latest date where Batch.batchypeFk = Student.batchTypeFk having in mind that there could be as many batch with different batch types and as many student as possible with batch types using sql server

I have an attempt like this in mind, but its not solving the problem as it has sql errors

```
UPDATE a.batchName
  FROM STUDENT a, BATCH b
  where a.batchTypeFk == b.batchTypeFk orderby data asc
```

Comment: As per your expectation, BatchName for Rob should be updated with Mtt, right?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: Just because there's a `Students` table referenced in the question, [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
UPDATE S
SET S.name = C.name
FROM student  S
INNER JOIN
(
    --Picking Name by joining to the same table
    --Based on the Max Date and batchTypeFk 
    --selectted in the sub query
    SELECT A.batchTypeFk,B.name 
    FROM 
    (
        --Here only select MAX Date per batchTypeFk
        SELECT batchTypeFk,MAX(date) date
        FROM batch 
        GROUP BY batchTypeFk 
    )A
    INNER JOIN batch B ON A.batchTypeFk = B.batchTypeFk AND A.date = B.date
)C ON S.batchTypeFk = C.batchTypeFk
```

Comment: I donot understand this >>> SELECT A.batchTypeFk,B.name 
    FROM 
    (...... can u break it down

Comment: Added some comments in the script. Check it helped or not.

Comment: As "Name" from Batch table can not be collected while selecting the Latest date, I just collect the "Name" for the selected max Date by joining the same table again. A only returns "1 | 05/20/2019". Then I join A with batch (B) again to get the "Name" value for "1 | 05/20/2019".

Answer (score 0):

I think , You can update like this.

```sql
Create Table #Batch
(
Id Int
,name varchar(50)
,batchTypeFk Int
,date datetime
)

Insert Into #Temp_St
Values
(1,'Rob',1,'Eng')

Insert Into #Batch
Values
(1,'Eng','1','20190518')
,(2,'Mtt',1,'20190520')
```

With Cte

```sql
As
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By date desc) as rn,s.*
From #Batch b
Inner Join #Temp_St s On b.batchTypeFk=s.batchTypeFk
)
```

Update Cte

```sql
Set batchName='Summer' 
Where rn=1
```